# Are there examples of anti-semitism in Roald Dahl's publications?

Tags: roald-dahl

Roald Dahl's families have apologised for anti-Semitic statements he made (without, I think, being specific about where these appeared).

[This BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-55205354) identifies interviews where offensive statements were made.

Do his published work (either for children or for adults) contain anything that might be considered anti-Semitic?

Comment: The BBC mentioned only the interviews but Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roald_Dahl#Antisemitism) mentions his first novel, *Sometime Never*, and a short story entitled "Madame Rosette."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I did read the Wikipedia article, but obviously not carefully enough.